# jQuery echo a variable twice or how to increment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input fields that will be generated dynamically by jQuery. Each time a button will be pressed there will be added two input fields. To handle the names there is an auto increment for `n`.  Now I thought I could use just one variable `n` to name the input tags.

```
$(wrapper).append("<input class='add' name='xdata_" + n + "' placeholder='type in' type='text' value=''><input class='add' name='xdata_"+ n++ +"' placeholder='Datum' type='text' value=''>");
```

First name tag will show the correct `n`. The problem is the second `n++` which will just echo `n` same as the first even when it should increment by `n++`. When setting a second variable it works, but I wanted to shorten code. So I would like to know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `++n`(pre-increment) instead of `n++`(post-increment)

```
$(wrapper).append("<input class='add' name='xdata_" + n + "' placeholder='type in' type='text' value=''><input class='add' name='xdata_"+ ++n +"' placeholder='Datum' type='text' value=''>");
```